# Having problems with Python SOAP using Suds

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm having problems with Suds and I can't figure out what makes it behave like this.
I'm trying to call a webservice and that service takes one complex type as an
argument (ShippingGuideRequestType). I'll post my pdb session and try to explain what
is happening. The 'request' variable you see is of type ShippingGuideRequestType and
it is created using client.factory.create("ShippingGuideRequestType").

```
(Pdb) request
(ShippingGuideRequestType){
   UserInformation = 
      (UserInformationType){
         Usercode = None
      }
   RequestProperties = 
      (RequestPropertiesType){
         SchemaVersion = None
         Language = None
         WithPrice = None
         WithExpectedDelivery = None
         WithGuiInformation = None
         NumberOfAlternativeDeliveryDates = None
         EDI = None
         PostingAtPostoffice = None
         Trace = None
      }
   ProductIds = 
      (ProductIdsType){
         ProductId[] = <empty>
      }
   Consignment = 
      (ConsignmentInputType){
         FromCountryCode = None
         FromPostalCode = None
         ToCountryCode = None
         ToPostalCode = None
         ShippingDate = 
            (DateAndTimeType){
               Year = None
               Month = None
               Day = None
               Hour = None
               Minute = None
            }
         EarlyCollectionAtTerminal = None
         AdditionalServices = 
            (AdditionalServicesInputType){
               AdditionalService[] = <empty>
            }
      }
   Packages = 
      (PackagesInputType){
         Package[] = <empty>
      }
 }
```

The ShippingGuideRequestType looks OK, now let's try to populate the required
fields with data. Let's first deal with the UserInformation property. This is
created using client.factory.create("UserInformationType"):

```
(Pdb) userInformation
(UserInformationType){
   Usercode = "-CENCORED-"
 }
```

Now let's handle the ProductIds which is created using
client.factory.create("ProductIdsType"):

```
(Pdb) productsInput
(ProductIdsType){
   ProductId[] = 
      "SERVICEPAKKE",
 }
```

The final required property is the PackagesInputType, this is created in a bit
more complex manner. First I create the PackagesInputType, then I create an array
of PackageInputType (using client.factory.create("PackageInputType")).

```
(Pdb) packagesInput
(PackagesInputType){
   Package[] = 
      (PackageInputType){
         Height = 
            (UnitCodeLengthType){
               value = 10
               _unitCode = "CMT"
            }
         Width = 
            (UnitCodeLengthType){
               value = 10
               _unitCode = "CMT"
            }
         Length = 
            (UnitCodeLengthType){
               value = 10
               _unitCode = "CMT"
            }
         GrossWeight = 
            (UnitCodeWeightType){
               value = 1000
               _unitCode = "GRM"
            }
         Volume = 
            (UnitCodeCubicType){
               value = None
               _unitCode = "DMQ"
            }
         VolumeSpecial = None
         FromCountryCode = None
         FromPostalCode = "7800"
         ToCountryCode = None
         ToPostalCode = "7041"
         ShippingDate = 
            (DateAndTimeType){
               Year = None
               Month = None
               Day = None
               Hour = None
               Minute = None
            }
         AdditionalServices = 
            (AdditionalServicesInputType){
               AdditionalService[] = <empty>
            }
         EarlyCollectionAtTerminal = None
         _packageId = "myRef"
      },
 }
(Pdb) request.UserInformation = userInformation
(Pdb) request.ProductIds = productsInput
(Pdb) request.Packages = packagesInput
(Pdb) request
(ShippingGuideRequestType){
   UserInformation = 
      (UserInformationType){
         Usercode = "-CENCORED"
      }
   RequestProperties = 
      (RequestPropertiesType){
         SchemaVersion = None
         Language = None
         WithPrice = None
         WithExpectedDelivery = None
         WithGuiInformation = None
         NumberOfAlternativeDeliveryDates = None
         EDI = None
         PostingAtPostoffice = None
         Trace = None
      }
   ProductIds = 
      (ProductIdsType){
         ProductId[] = 
            "SERVICEPAKKE",
      }
   Consignment = 
      (ConsignmentInputType){
         FromCountryCode = None
         FromPostalCode = None
         ToCountryCode = None
         ToPostalCode = None
         ShippingDate = 
            (DateAndTimeType){
               Year = None
               Month = None
               Day = None
               Hour = None
               Minute = None
            }
         EarlyCollectionAtTerminal = None
         AdditionalServices = 
            (AdditionalServicesInputType){
               AdditionalService[] = <empty>
            }
      }
   Packages = 
      (PackagesInputType){
         Package[] = 
            (PackageInputType){
               Height = 
                  (UnitCodeLengthType){
                     value = 10
                     _unitCode = "CMT"
                  }
               Width = 
                  (UnitCodeLengthType){
                     value = 10
                     _unitCode = "CMT"
                  }
               Length = 
                  (UnitCodeLengthType){
                     value = 10
                     _unitCode = "CMT"
                  }
               GrossWeight = 
                  (UnitCodeWeightType){
                     value = 1000
                     _unitCode = "GRM"
                  }
               Volume = 
                  (UnitCodeCubicType){
                     value = None
                     _unitCode = "DMQ"
                  }
               VolumeSpecial = None
               FromCountryCode = None
               FromPostalCode = "7800"
               ToCountryCode = None
               ToPostalCode = "7041"
               ShippingDate = 
                  (DateAndTimeType){
                     Year = None
                     Month = None
                     Day = None
                     Hour = None
                     Minute = None
                  }
               AdditionalServices = 
                  (AdditionalServicesInputType){
                     AdditionalService[] = <empty>
                  }
               EarlyCollectionAtTerminal = None
               _packageId = "myRef"
            },
      }
 }
```

In my point of view the structure looks fine, now let's try to call the service.

```
(Pdb) self.client.service.ShippingGuide(request) 
2011-02-28 14:32:37 ERROR suds.client <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.bring.no/logistics/shippingguide/1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:ShippingGuideRequest>
         <ns0:UserInformation>
            <ns0:UserInformation>
               <ns0:Usercode>-CENCORED-</ns0:Usercode>
            </ns0:UserInformation>
            <ns0:RequestProperties>
               <ns0:SchemaVersion/>
            </ns0:RequestProperties>
            <ns0:ProductIds>
               <ns0:ProductId>SERVICEPAKKE</ns0:ProductId>
            </ns0:ProductIds>
            <ns0:Packages>
               <ns0:Package packageId="myRef">
                  <ns0:Height unitCode="CMT">10</ns0:Height>
                  <ns0:Width unitCode="CMT">10</ns0:Width>
                  <ns0:Length unitCode="CMT">10</ns0:Length>
                  <ns0:GrossWeight unitCode="GRM">1000</ns0:GrossWeight>
                  <ns0:Volume unitCode="DMQ"/>
                  <ns0:FromCountryCode/>
                  <ns0:FromPostalCode>7800</ns0:FromPostalCode>
                  <ns0:ToCountryCode/>
                  <ns0:ToPostalCode>7041</ns0:ToPostalCode>
               </ns0:Package>
            </ns0:Packages>
         </ns0:UserInformation>
         <ns0:RequestProperties/>
         <ns0:ProductIds/>
         <ns0:Packages/>
      </ns0:ShippingGuideRequest>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
*** WebFault: Server raised fault: 'FG_INPUT_003 User information missing from request. [errorId cf19f72b-0795-4f58-8a70-a8c1846ba186]'
```

What happened here? Why is everything encoded within the UserInformation element?

Answer (score 0):

Have you give this a go:

```
shipping = client.factory.create("ShippingGuideRequestType")

shipping.UserInformation.UserCode = val1

shipping.RequestProperties.SchemaVersion = val2
shipping.RequestProperties.Language = val3

//Add the rest of the values.

client.service.shippingFunction(shipping)
```