# [python-suds]Bug? One additional element is created when using Factory

Tags: soap, suds

I am using suds to call web service, but the debug log shows that the xml elements are not correct. It added one additional parent element. Does anyone know this is a bug or not? How to fix it? **Why is everything encoded within the assignmentID element?** Sorry, I don't know how to post xml content. I saw a same post here: [Having problems with Python SOAP using Suds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142848/having-problems-with-python-soap-using-suds)

--code snippet--

```
    cl = Client(url)
    submitRes = cl.factory.create('submitResult')
    submitRes.assignmentID = elem.assignmentID
    submitRes.actualTime = '30'
    submitRes.bugID = '';
    submitRes.note = 'submit result from python client webserice'
    submitRes.status = 'FAIL' 
    submitRes.build = 'build03'
    print cl.service.submitResult(submitRes)
```

Comment: *the xml output*<ns0:submitResult>
         <assignmentID>
            <assignmentID>2361719</assignmentID>
            <status>FAIL</status>
            <build>build03</build>
            <actualTime>30</actualTime>
            <bugID></bugID>
            <note>submit result from python client webserice</note>
         </assignmentID>
      </ns0:submitResult>

Answer (score 0):

When you print your WSDL it should have the function submitResult(). This should have a parameter say called `ns4:result`. So if the method is like `submitResult(ns4:result)` use `factory.create('ns4:result')`. Don't use the function name. Then pass `result` into `cl.service.submitResult(result)`. I cannot know for sure this will work without looking at the wsdl but it should work if the WSDL is in this format.

Thanks,
Chris